# How to stop error being displayed in firebug?

Tags: jquery

The code below works fine, but when I enter incorrect login details, I get '`NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://.....`'

It also appears in the error count as well. Is is possible not to display this error?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#login").click(function(event){
              $.get( 
                 loginURL,
                 { authaccountid: $('#authaccountid').val(), authemail:$('#authemail').val(), authpassword:$('#authpassword').val()},function() {})
                .success(function() { alert("success"); })
                .error(function() { alert("error"); })
          });
       });
```

Comment: Since you're doing an ajax call you're in control of `loginURL` resource so when this is called with wrong credentials you could serve another page (and return a 200) instead of a 403 and check the response (in both cases) on success callback

Comment: It's just they way the Firebug console works: logging network errors. Why do you bother?